# Kann etwas »nachverfolgbar« sein?

Tags: word-usage

Ich erstelle derzeit ein technisches Dokument, das folgenden Satz enthält:

> Durch Reportingmechanismen sollen Entwicklungsprozesse auswertbar und nachverfolgbar werden.

Nun meckert Word über das Wort *nachverfolgbar* und schlägt auch keine Korrektur vor. Eine Google-Suche ergab:

- [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/nachverfolgen) findet zwar das Wort *nachverfolgen,* aber nicht *nachverfolgbar.* Das Wort *reizbar* wird beispielsweise gefunden.
- Linguee spuckt zwar einige sinnvolle Sätze (meinem Meinung nach) aus, markiert diese aber gleichzeitig mit: »Diese Übersetzung könnte eventuell nicht richtig sein.«
- Außerdem finden weder Dict.cc noch Synonyme.woxikon.de irgendwelche Ergebnisse.

Was hat es also mit dem Wort auf sich? Kann es problemlos benutzt werden?

Comment: Wenn später die Herkunft, die Geschichte, der Ablauf der Verarbeitung oder die Verteilung und Auslieferung nachvollzogen werden kann, spricht man normgerecht bei Produkten und Prozessen (ISO 9000) sowie bei Messungen (VIM = [JCGM 200](http://www.bipm.org/en/publications/guides/vim.html) sowie ISO/IEC Guide 99) von „Rückverfolgbarkeit“ (engl. “traceability”).

Comment: @Loong Würde ich als Antwort annehmen

Comment: Ich war mir nicht sicher, ob dieser Begriff tatsächlich das beschreibt, was du ausdrücken möchtest.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Natürlich gibt es Fälle, in denen *nachverfolgbar* das Wort der Wahl sein wird. Typische Beispiele immer dann, wenn Dinge real oder virtuell den Ort wechseln und diese Bewegung beobachtet und / oder dokumentiert wird:

Warenströme, Geld, wandernde Singvögel, ... können nachverfolgt werden, wenn diese also die Eigenschaft besitzen, dass das möglich ist, sind sie *nachverfolgbar*. Manchmal wird auch das kürzere *verfolgbar* benutzt, dies aber tendenziell mit zeitlichem Bezug zum Jetzt, mit *nach-* eher die Auswertung zu einem späteren Zeitpunkt. Linguee hat einige ganz gute Beispiele [hier](http://www.linguee.com/german-english/translation/nachverfolgbar+sind.html).

Bezieht sich die Beschreibung dagegen auf das Verstehen und quasi einem "Hinterherdenken" eines Vorgangs, würde man dagegen *nachvollziehen* beziehungsweise *nachvollziehbar* benutzen. Für den Fall aus der Frage wäre dies der passende Begriff.

Answer (score 1):

*Nachverfolgbar* ist zwar eine grammatisch korrekte Bildung und verständlich, stellt aber dennoch kein üblich gebrauchtes Wort dar.

Stattdessen würde man im Allgemeinen **nachvollziehbar** verwenden.